# Cannot import Firebase Firestore Colletion

Tags: javascript, reactjs, firebase, google-cloud-firestore, next.js

I'm trying to call a Firestore Colletion in my next app, here is the error that I get when running the app:

```
FirebaseError: Firebase: Firebase App named '[DEFAULT]' already exists (app/duplicate-app).
```

Here is my `firebase.js` code:

```
import firebase from 'firebase/app';
import "firebase/firestore"

const firebaseConfig = {};

  export const getPosts = async () => {
    firebase.initializeApp(firebaseConfig);
    
    const posts = await firebase.firestore().collection("articles").then((snapshot) => {
      const snapshotVal = snapshot.val();

      const result = [];
      for (var slug in snapshotVal) {
        const post = snapshotVal[slug];
        result.push(post);
      }
      return result.reverse();
    });
    return posts      
  };
```

Answer (score 1):

Because you keep trying to initialize a new firebase app every time you `getPosts`, so you should check first if there isn't a firebase app before `initializeApp`,

try something like this before `getPosts` function:

```
var firebase_app;

if (!firebase.apps.length) {
  firebase_app = firebase.initializeApp(firebaseConfig);
} else {
  firebase_app = firebase.app(); // if already initialized, use that one
}
```